# How to get the selected row from a gtkmm treeview

Tags: c++, user-interface, treeview, selection, gtkmm

I have a gtkmm TreeView using ListStore. I am using this as a static list selection menu. I am having problems seeing when the user changes rows and which row is selected.

I have attempted to use `m_TreeView.signal_row_activated().connect( sigc::mem_fun(*this, &optionList::row_activated) );` but get the error of

```
error: no match for call to ‘(sigc::bound_mem_functor0<void, optionList>) (const Gtk::TreePath&, Gtk::TreeViewColumn* const&)’ { return functor_(_A_arg1, _A_arg2); }
```

I have also attempted to use changed signals, but I receive the same errors. I have not been fruitful in finding these errors on Google. I have also not seen another way to create a static list selection menu.

My code is as follows:

```cpp
optionList::optionList() {
    set_policy(Gtk::POLICY_AUTOMATIC, Gtk::POLICY_AUTOMATIC);

    add(m_TreeView);

    m_refListStore = Gtk::ListStore::create(m_Columns);

    m_TreeView.set_model(m_refListStore);
    m_TreeView.set_activate_on_single_click(true);

    std::array<Glib::ustring, 3> options = {"Status", "Plugins", "Config"};

    for(const auto & option : options) {
        std::ostringstream text;
        text << option;

        Gtk::TreeModel::Row row = *(m_refListStore->append());
        row[m_Columns.m_col_text] = text.str();
    }

    m_TreeView.append_column("Options", m_Columns.m_col_text);

    m_TreeView.signal_state_changed().connect( sigc::mem_fun(*this, &optionList::row_activated) ); //This line produces the error


    show_all_children();
}
```

the `optionList::row_activated` function is just a `cout` so I know it's at least being activated. If I remove the connecting line, then it compiles and runs fine, but I don't have any way to tell if it's being selected.

I am expecting to see the phrase `A row has been selected` in the console (as that is what `row_activated` outputs) every time I select a different row. However, I am not able to even compile the code with the aforementioned line included.

At the very least, how can I resolve this connection issue so that the code can compile and activate the function?

Edit: I believe that I was messing up and needed to send using `sigc::bind()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answer I could come up with is that I was not properly passing and to do this I need to use

```cpp
m_TreeView.signal_state_changed().connect( sigc::bind(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &optionList::row_activated), any parameters) );
```